# Show that one cannot prove the following formula by natural deduction

Tags: predicate-logic, natural-deduction

> Show that one cannot prove the following formula by natural deduction:
>
> $$\exists x \; \forall y\;R_0(x,y)\to
> \forall x \; \exists y\;  R_0(x,y)$$

So I have to find a case where I get truth values $1 \rightarrow 0$, right?

Comment: Do you mean $R_0$? $R0(x,y)$ reads odd.

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If this were true, what would happen if the truth or falsehood of $R0(x,y)$ did not depend on $y$ at all?

Your (deleted) example was a good start, but in basic logic, $x$ and $y$ have to be the same "type" - you can't have $x$ range amongst people and $y$ range amongst money.

Instead, what if $x,y$ ranged amongst people, and $R0(x,y)$  means

> $x=y$ or $x$ gave $y$ money

Comment: Like "if some people have climbed the top 10 highest mountains, then everyone has climbed some of the 10 highest mountains"?

Comment: That's a close example, but in basic logic, we try to have only one "type," and you have two types here, "people" and "mountains." You can get away with it, but it is better to try to consider a case where $x,y$ vary over the same collection of possible values.

Comment: Ok, but if R0 is "gave money" and x,y are people then how do the quantifiers work out? "Some user63764 gave money to all the Thomas Andrews"?

Comment: Depends on your domain. For example, if your domain is three people, the first statement is, "there is a person who gave money to everybody else", and the second statement is, "every person gave money to somebody." Can you think of a case where the first is true, but the second is not true?

Comment: someone is taller than anyone else -> everyone is taller than someone else. Thanks @Thomas Andrews

Comment: "Someone is taller than everyone else." "Anyone," in English, is a vaguer term, and does not mean "everyone."